# Passing through events and props to/from a root element

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to create a re-usable button.  Is there any way to pass props and events down to the button itself without having to account for all the different possibilities?

For example, if I set a type on the `<new-button>` component, it passes the type to the `<button>` without me having to add a 'type' prop to the `<new-button>` component?   Same goes for events, can a click event trigger from the button itself?

The component template itself is fairly simple and the button is the root component:

```
<template>
    <button :disabled="submitting">
        <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" v-show="submitting"></i>
        <i v-if="icon" :class="icon" v-show="!submitting"></i>
        <slot></slot>
    </button>
</template>
```

I do know that the class attribute passes through, but I don't see any way of passing through anything else.

Answer (score 3):

#### How to pass all props down

If you want to pass all props down to an element without having to specify each of the props in particular, the way to achieve it is to pass the [$props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-props) object (containing all the props passed to the component) using [v-bind](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind).

parent:

```
<custom-button :prop1="alice" :prop2="has" :prop3="a" :prop4="cat">
```

child:

```
<button v-bind="$props">

export default { 
  props: ['prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3', 'prop4'] 
}
```

#### How to prevent declaring all props

As you see, we still have to declare all the props in the `props` option of the component though. Luckily there's a workaround for that. Let's just pass an object of props:

parent:

```
<custom-button :props="{ prop1, prop2, prop3, prop4 }">
```

child:

```
<button v-bind="props">

export default {
  props: ['props']
}
```

#### How to listen to native events

Finally for emitting events, you can register listeners for [native Javascript events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components), such as `click` or `input` which bubble from HTML elements.

parent:

```
<custom-button @click.native="doStuff">
```

child:

```
<button>
```

Comment: Trying to avoid having to define all the possible props for a button, but the native events do work as expected.  Thanks.

Comment: I'll update my answer to let you avoid props definition.

Comment: done. if you want me to elaborate on any part, feel free to ask